# RoR Many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many

I have Category and Specification models and many to many association via CategoriesSpecifications table which looks like this:

```
create_table :categories_specifications, id: false do |t|
   t.belongs_to :specification, null: false
   t.belongs_to :category, null: false
   t.integer :status, null: false, default: 0
end
```

What is best practice and shortest way to select all specifications via Category

Answer (score 0):

```
@category = Category.first
@category.specifications # this is the shortest way to select all specifications via Category
```

Make sure the associations are declared in your models, of course:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_specifications
  has_many :specifications, through: :categories_specifications
end

class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_specifications
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_specifications
end

class CategoriesSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :specification
end
```

**Recommended reading:** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like the below:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specifications
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_specifications
end

class CategoriesSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :specification
end

class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_specifications
  has_many :categories, :through => :categories_specifications
end
```

You can simple find the `category` and than select all `specifications`:

```
Category.find(1).specifications
```